# Makefile does not find rule for object

Tags: c, makefile, rule

I have a beginner's question about a Makefile. I have a very simple makefile containing:

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -lm -std=c99 -g -o0
EXEC = test
BUILDDIR = build
OBJDIR = obj
SOURCES = $(shell cat sources.list)
DEPS = $(shell cat headers.list)
OBJ = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
OBJECTS = $(patsubst %,$(OBJDIR)/%,$(OBJ))

all: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $(BUILDDIR)/$(EXEC)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(BUILDDIR)/$(EXEC) $(OBJDIR)/*.o
```

My Problem is, if I try to use this Makefile to compile, it returns the error message:

```
there is no rule for the target obj/Name.o
```

What am I doing wrong?

After the first few comments and further research I got to this working Version, but it does not create the object files in the obj folder, so it is not what I aim for

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -lm -std=c99 -g -o0
EXEC = test
BUILDDIR = build
OBJDIR = obj
SOURCES = $(shell cat sources.list)
DEPS = $(shell cat headers.list)
OBJ = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
OBJECTS = $(patsubst %,$(OBJDIR)/%,$(OBJ))

all: $(BUILDDIR)/$(EXEC)

$(BUILDDIR)/$(EXEC): $(OBJ)
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o  $(BUILDDIR)/$(EXEC)

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
$(CC) -c $< -o $@


clean:
rm -f $(BUILDDIR)/$(EXEC) $(OBJDIR)/*.o
```

Comment: Does `Name.c` exist, in the top-level directory?

Comment: yes, otherwise the makefile would not require the .o to be build

Comment: Is there name.c in your `sources.list` file?

Comment: Not solving the problem at all but yet, `-lm` should be in variable `LD_FLAGS` instead of `CFLAGS`.

Comment: Also with the way this makefile is written you will always do linking because you will never create a `all` file.

Comment: i dont want to create an all file, can you explain this?

Comment: Replace `all` by `$(BUILDDIR)/$(EXEC)` in your current `all` rule. Add a `all` rule bfore with no command: `all:$(BUILDDIR)/$(EXEC)`, and add a `.PHONY` directive: `.PHONY:all clean`. `.PHONY` sets the list of targets who are not actual files.

Comment: I get the same message error than you when trying to build a `obj/toto.o` file while `toto.c` is not present.

Comment: Your comment answering to Tom Karzes is all wrong.

Comment: but the file is present and included in my sources list. Thanks for the other comment, i adapted my script accordingly

Comment: No error with the case? You seem to be running on linux, so file names are case sensitive.

Comment: You can set `SOUCES=$(wildcard *.c)` or `SOUCES=$(wildcard *.c */*.c)` to avoid such errors.

Comment: I am using the file lists for the sources, because the folder contains .c files, which i do not want to compile. The .o files the makefile complains about are available in the main Folder as .c files. I checked the cases

Comment: Did you post your whole makefile? There is no `vpath` directive sooner that you would not have shown us?

Comment: I tried your makefile on Windows with `type` instead of `cat`, I got no problem, there must be something important you are not telling us.

Comment: added the working Version to my Initial question, but how can i get the makefile to create the files inside the obj folder

Comment: Do you have sources with the same file name in your `src` directory (but in different sub-directories of course)?

Answer (score 1):

Are all the files in headers.list present at the right place ?

By the way, this is not a good way to handle dependencies on headers. You should take a look at `-MP` and `-MDD` and other options of your preprocessor to generate dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

A classical makefile which should do what you need:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-std=c99 -g -o0
LDFLAGS=-lm
EXEC=test
BUILDDIR=build/
OBJDIR=obj/
SOURCES=$(shell cat sources.list)
OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.c,$(OBJDIR)%.o,$(notdir $(SOURCES)))

vpath %.c $(sort $(dir $(SOURCES)))

.PHONY:all mrproper clean depends

all:$(BUILDDIR)$(EXEC)

$(BUILDDIR)$(EXEC):$(OBJECTS)|$(BUILDDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(OBJDIR)%.o:%.c|$(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

$(BUILDDIR) $(OBJDIR):
    mkdir $@

mrproper:clean
    rm -f $(BUILDDIR)$(EXEC)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS)

depends:
    @rm -f dependencies.mk
    @for i in $(SOURCES); do $(CC) -MM $$i -MT $(OBJDIR)`basename $$i | sed s:.c$$:.o:` >> dependencies.mk; done

include $(wildcard dependencies.mk)
```

If something is not clear, let me know.

Usage:

```
make depends
make
```